Configure P4V default workspace creation root
I have some directory where I want all my Perforce workspaces to be located at.
When creating workspace in Perforce P4V, it suggesting some root directory and I need each time to set it to the location I want it.
Is there is the way to  configure P4V default root directory to point to where I really want it all the times?

The client root defaults to the client's CWD, so maybe if you modify your P4V shortcut to run in the desired directory?  You don't say what OS you're on.  Note that you DO NOT want your workspaces to all share one exact root (but having them all under a common parent directory is fine and normal).

I am in windows, added label now. And you are correct, I want the parent directory of the root to be same, not the root itself

Ah, just tried it out now and it looks like P4V overrides the default with its own autogenerated folder (which doesn't seem to be configurable any way that I could find).  Maybe a custom tool would be the best option -- you could create the workspace with scripted defaults, and then if you want to use P4V's workspace editor you can use it on the existing workspace (which will have your selected root already set).

It seems like the default parent directory when creating workspace is the parent directory of the current used workspace.
Hence you need to work on workspace which has the same parent directory as you want in order to get it by default instead of browsing to it.
I can't find a way to make it in fixed place.

This is not helping when no workspace selected

It is recommended to use triggers to process the %formfile% when identifying the creation instructions.This is highly customizable
